# image border and image itself is overflowing

Tags: html, css, border, margin

```
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z4ls0-ZGnU4/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href='C:\Users\eagle\demo-projects\tribute-page\style.css' type="text/css">
```

---

```
html body{
  margin:0;
}

.img {

  display:block;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}
```

Scroll bar at the bottom making it go left and right and not still?

Comment: what do you mean it wont fit to your current width?

Comment: ah my bad let me rephrase, my sides are going left and right and it has a scroll bar to move left and right when i want everything to stay in place? thank you!

Comment: if you still dont get it, try this                                                                                               * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html body{
  margin:0;
}

.img {

  display:block;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

} i just added defualt style in * https://codepen.io/hubmotivator/pen/ExPvvJL

Comment: RE: duplicate - "CSS: Width in percentage and Borders" - doesn't seem like the same - question to me.

Comment: I can't answer the question officially - because it's been closed - but check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/g281h034/